# Fizz! Buzz! 'ave a banana!

Tags: code-golf

Here's one for fans of [Cabin Pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabin_Pressure_(radio_series)). There is an episode in which the characters devise a new version of Fizz Buzz, which is simplified to contain absolutely no mathematics.

It has these rules:

- If someone says "fizz", you say "buzz".
- If someone says "buzz", you sing "'ave a banana"
- If someone says your name, you say "fizz".

The result is that whenever a name is uttered, that person says "fizz" and the sequence has to run to completion.

---

Let's write some code.

I'd like you to write a program/function/whatever which works thus:

- It accepts one single string of text as input.
- If the string equals the name of the language your code is written in, it outputs "fizz".
- If the string equals "fizz", it outputs "buzz".
- If the string equals "buzz", it outputs "'ave a banana" (note the apostrophe at the start).
- If the input is not one of these things, it should terminate.
- Here's the kicker: The output string must go to two places.
- - Output to be seen by the user
- - Back into your code as input
- I don't really care if they are output in each iteration, or build a string for eventual output.
- Outputs must be separated by new lines (in console or result string)

## Rules

- This is code golf, write in any language you like and attempt to make your code as small as possible.
- Standard loopholes apply.
- I'd like to see links to an online interpreter.
- The language name can be a full name or common short-form of the language the answer is written in. E.g. JS is acceptable, but shortening Ruby to R is not).

## Test Cases

Input

```
'buzz'
```

Output

```
'ave a banana
```

---

Input

```
'fizz'
```

Output

```
buzz
'ave a banana
```

---

Input

```
ruby # or the name of the language your answer is written in
```

Output

```
fizz
buzz
'ave a banana
```

---

Input

```
something else
```

No output

Comment: What is the name of my language?

Comment: @Adám Whichever language you are writing your answer in. Is there a better way I could express that?

Comment: @KrzysztofSzewczyk [Nope](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205798/43319).

Comment: @AJFaraday I meant to ask what kind of freedom we have. JavaScript/js/ES6; APL/Dyalog APL (Unicode); Python/Python 3/Python 3.8…

Comment: @Adám I’m happy with short forms like ES6 or JS.

Comment: But what happens if your name is Buzz? Or Banana?

Comment: @darrylyeo That's an interesting question. I am unable to find any programming languages named Fizz or Banana (it's free real estate ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ ). There is a language named Buzz, but it appears to be designed to instruct swarming automata, so I'm fairly confident we're not going to get any answers in buzz.

Comment: @darrylyeo As for the game being played by people, I'd expect it to become a kind of rhythmic ostinato until Buzz gets bored of playing and gives it up.

Comment: Apart from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205793/63348), and [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205807/63348) and (this)[https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205822/63348], everyone seems to be missing `The output string must go [...] Back into your code as input`, thus rendering the challenge as just (in Python-like pseudocode) `print text[findIndex(input)+1:].join('\n')`.

Comment: @KenY-N I'm treating them based on the output, not the method.

Comment: @AJFaraday However, [a language called "A" does exist](https://esolangs.org/wiki/A)...

Comment: @Chronocidal That's okay, "'ave a banana" |= 'A'

Comment: I'm voting this as unclear until there is a specification for how we determine a language's name.

Comment: @AdHocGarfHunter That's fairly petty.

Comment: I have looked up the meaning of petty, but I don't know what you are trying to communicate to me.

Comment: @AdHocGarfHunter I have clarified what can be used as the language name.

Answer (score 12):

## perl -M5.010 -n, 47 bytes

```
"Perl\nfizz\nbuzz\n'ave a banana"=~/\b$_/;say$'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18pAEjH5KVlVlXF5CWVgkj1xLJUhUSFpMQ8IFSyrdOPSVKJ17cuTqxUUf//H6Se619@QUlmfl7xf11fUz0DQ4P/unkA)

Prints whatever is following the input, or nothing if there is no match. Assumes input is newline terminated.

Comment: Nice! Can't get anything shorter using lists... You can save three bytes using literal newlines though!

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 26 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“Çȥȧ>$ỌĿɦ@⁴Ƙ½Æ/ṠṫḞƇ»Ỵṣ⁸ḊẎY
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AVEArv9qZWxsef//4oCcw4fIpcinPiThu4zEv8mmQOKBtMaYwr3Dhi/huaDhuavhuJ7Gh8K74bu04bmj4oG44biK4bqOWf///ydhdmUgYSBiYW5hbmE)**

#### How?

```
“...»Ỵṣ⁸ḊẎY - Link: list of characters, W
“...»       - compressed string = "Jelly\nfizz\nbuzz\n'ave a banana"
     Ỵ      - split at newlines = ["Jelly","fizz","buzz","'ave a banana"]
      ṣ     - split at:
       ⁸    -   chain's left argument, W  e.g. "Jelly" -> [[],["fizz","buzz","'ave a banana"]]
        Ḋ   - dequeue                                   = [["fizz","buzz","'ave a banana"]]
         Ẏ  - tighten                                   = ["fizz","buzz","'ave a banana"]
          Y - join with new lines                       = "fizz\nbuzz\n'ave a banana"
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 63 bytes

```bash
bash=fizz
fizz=buzz
buzz="'ave a banana"
echo ${x=${!1}}&&$0 $x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvgf4BjiYatnpQKi/ycBRWzTMququECEbVIpkAUibJXUE8tSFRIVkhLzgFCJKzU5I19BpbrCVqVa0bC2Vk1NxUBBpeL/f7AJAA)

This requires `.` to be in your `PATH`.  If that's not acceptable, then replace `$0` with `./$0` (assuming the program is being run from the current working directory) at the cost of 2 bytes (65 bytes total).

Input is passed as an argument, output is on stdout. The language name is entered as `bash`.

(There's spurious output to stderr, but that's OK under our generic rules.)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>46</s> 33 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
’
05AB1E
fizz
ÒÖ
'ž™ a æé’I¶.ø¡¦θ
```

-13 bytes by porting [*@Abigail*'s Perl answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205794/52210), so make sure to upvote her!!

Outputs `[]` for invalid inputs.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcNMLgNTRydDV660zKoqrsOTDk/jUj@671HLIoVEhcPLDq8EqvA8tE3v8I5DCw8tO7fj/3@IcgA)

**Original 46 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) approach:**

```
"fizz"U•äƵí•hRQiX=}XQi'ÒÖ=}'ÒÖQi’'ž™ a æé’,}õ?
```

Outputs nothing for invalid inputs.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fKS2zqkop9FHDosNLjm09vBbIyAgKzIywrY0IzFQ/POnwNNtaMBWY@ahhpvrRfY9aFikkKhxednglkK9Te3ir/f//BqaOToauAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
’
05AB1E
fizz
ÒÖ
'ž™ a æé’         '# Push dictionary string "\n05AB1E\nfizz\nbuzz\n'ave a banana"
         I         # Push the input
          ¶.ø      # Surround it with leading and trailing newline
             ¡     # Split the string on this
              ¦    # Remove the first part (for invalid inputs)
               θ   # Pop and only leave the last part (or an empty list)
                   # (and output it implicitly as result)

"fizz"U            # Puts "fizz" in variable `X`
•äƵí•              # Push compressed integer 14793296
     h             # Convert it to hexadecimal: E1BA50
      R            # Reverse it to 05AB1E
       Qi  }       # If the (implicit) input-string is equal to this:
         X         #  Push "fizz" from variable `X`
          =        #  Print it with trailing newline without popping
X                  # Push "fizz" from variable `X`
 Qi    }           # If the top of the stack equals "fizz",
                   # which will use the (implicit) input if the stack is empty:
   'ÒÖ            '#  Push dictionary string "buzz"
      =            #  Print it with trailing newline without popping
'ÒÖQi           } '# If the top of the stack (or implicit input) equals "buzz":
     ’'ž™ a æé’   '#  Push dictionary string "'ave a banana"
               ,   #  Pop and print it
õ?                 # Print "" without newline
                   # (for invalid input, which otherwise would be output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to use the dictionary?* and *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•äƵí•` is `14793296`; `'ÒÖ` is `"buzz"`; and `’'ž™ a æé’` is `"'ave a banana"`.

Comment: [You forgot to check for word boundaries](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcNMA1NHJ0NXrrTMqiquw5MOT@NSP7rvUcsihUSFw8sOrwQq8Dy08NCyczv@/1dSUgKqAZIA). I initially made that mistake as well.

Comment: @Abigail Thanks for letting me know. Fixed at the cost of 4 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 64 bytes

Expects `"js"` for the language name. Returns an array of strings.

```javascript
s=>[k="js","fizz","buzz","'ave a banana"].filter(w=>k*(k|=s==w))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY1NDoIwEIX3nqLpxtYoNxguYlwMOMXS2jFMhYR499rgTvIWL/nyfkacUfrJv/Il8Z2KgyLQXgPoUfRZO7@u1br3ZkecSaHqMFXpW@N8zDSZBdpwMuEDArBYW3pOwpGayINx5le29vCHt@k9rrd7KPyk/PBpUBSFaqB8AQ)

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 56 bytes

```
$
¶Retina¶fizz¶buzz¶'ave a banana
^(.*¶)(.*¶)*?(\1|.*$)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX4Xr0LYgMP/QtrTMqqpD25JKQaR6YlmqQqJCUmIeEHLFaehpHdqmCSG17DViDGv0tFQ0uf7/h@jlAmnlAunkQtEIAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
$
¶Retina¶fizz¶buzz¶'ave a banana
```

Append the possible inputs and outputs.

```
^(.*¶)(.*¶)*?(\1|.*$)
```

Try to delete only up to and including a line matching the original input. If this is not possible, then just delete everything.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>77</s> 76 bytes

```python
t="Python","fizz","buzz","'ave a banana"
*map(print,t[t.index(input())+1:]),
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7BCsIwDIbveYqQi62OgXgr7B28i4d2rVhwXWkz2fbys91OJofkT0j@Ly78HsNt60frsEMi2rij@z6lhl5@XUsx015O@utQo9GhJMF50FHE5AM3/ODWB@tm4UOcWEh5uaqnbLbyEPwQx8SYlwyvMWFGH6poM1sfFOB@Usw/ejBWK6yb5KOQgJwW5WbXi8pXtJt7F1lh1DkD7t6CuiNIbgc3VGqozPBHDNr0Fo7@Bw)

Takes input from `STDIN`, and print the results to `STDOUT`.

Comment: @JoKing that's really cool, thanks! Not sure why putting the comma makes it work.

Comment: It is the creation of a tuple (defined by a single comma) and using [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) that makes it work.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 43 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
'APL' 'fizz' 'buzz' '''ave a banana'(↑⍳↓⊣)⊂
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X90xwEddQT0ts6oKSCWVgil19cSyVIVEhaTEPCBU13jUNvFR7@ZHbZMfdS3WfNTV9D/tUduER719j7qaD603Bsn2TQ0OcgaSIR6ewf/TFMCmcunq6nKlQc2GccA2wDjlGYklqWXF6gA)

List of string literals is quite expensive...

#### How it works

```apl
S←'APL' 'fizz' 'buzz' '''ave a banana'  ⍝ Let's call this array S
S(↑⍳↓⊣)⊂  ⍝ The function
S( ⍳  )⊂  ⍝ 1-based index of the input in S, 5 if not found
    ↓⊣    ⍝ Drop that many items from the start of S
  ↑       ⍝ Convert the remaining items to be placed on each line
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 117 bytes

```java
void a(String s){System.out.println(s=s=="fizz"?"buzz":s=="buzz"?"'ave a banana":s=="java"?"fizz":"");if(s!="")a(s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY49DoMwDIVnOIXL0jCUA4AiTtCJsepgfhUKAeFAKYiz0zRBaisP8XvP9pcaJ7x0fSHr/LH3Y9qIDLIGieCKQsLqus7hkkKln6kTObQ6Y4kahKxud8ChIt@MOmZpBg6yeJoLzI@0PQfIvFIsi/eV6fgna/2RH1mOk003dzdIPHhA/pq8SBVt0I0q6LWnGsmIE@cWEdvT4ccwXeydcSoAIUWpyyaGF9uN0NMoUTI6cd0hIz/a9m1/Aw)

Comment: [112 bytes](https://tio.run/##jVBNawIxEL37K4aANNuNofToqr0VeigePJYeZnXXjl2zSzJZquJvT5NVCh4KMswX83hveDvscbLbfAfad61l2MVde6ZG196smVqjH4vRukHn4B3JwGkE0PmyoTU4Ro6tb2kD@3iTK7Zkth@fgHbrsgEK8HrlmV2u6tIWUMM8uMni1KMFnAuVlFVNx6MqfSwP2FeAUKKJIQoyDDRHTWZT/SxrKZTIXR5rVtiKvTVAs6cXIaaonS/doCEpd7qpzJa/ZJY/Z8U5FMNLdWtBJl2uHE9vvgVYHRxXe9161l1k4aj1ZjofcWM3NkvPf7NQA4GCWmPXNQeZtiwr/iFqjLwPGBXHJtJfAedRynMIyaGQHArJoXDj0C8) (because the OP says it's OK not to follow the method as long as the output is the correct one)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 39 bytes

```
≔⪪“Jε(h&]⦄_⁷¦⊗‹f·ⅈ⦄⊗x⍘ς3➙Ａ⁸“↑”¶υΦυ№…υκθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU8juCAns0RDyRkqHpOXlllVFZOXVAoi1RPLUhUSFZIS84BQSUdBKSZPSVNHoVTTmiugKDOvRMMtM6cktUijVEfBOb8UyHeuTM5Jdc7ILwAJZQOVFmpqalr//w8z/r9uWQ4A) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⪪“Jε(h&]⦄_⁷¦⊗‹f·ⅈ⦄⊗x⍘ς3➙Ａ⁸“↑”¶υ
```

Split the string `Charcoal\nfizz\nbuzz\n'ave a banana` on newlines and save the result in a variable.

```
Φυ№…υκθ
```

Filter on the result and show only those entries that appear after the input.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>115</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>105</s></sup> 98 bytes

Saved 4 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!

Saved 7 bytes thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)!!!

```c
i;*y[]={"c","fizz","buzz","'ave a banana"};f(char*s){for(i=0;i<3;)strcmp(s,y[i++])||puts(s=y[i]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7RaoMwFIbv@xSHwNiJplBYe7PUJ3G5SENsIyaKSQdqfXZ35iyMsT8XP0m@83HM/mrMsjiZDaUqJmaYYJUbR6rLfa1X/WlBw0UHOmyWFZqb7rPIp6rt0RUH6c5vksfUG99hFEPp8lzxx6O7p4ixoLvicl68dgE5TDugrIoMEhTgddO0Bk9ZdKNtNzvncuW89aYbMAkYBBz/RVJ5VKRhsfU23Vy4gm2iZT@ftCKgCwlqQg6S6gwnCXlePzf5TtcTUiF7ie8fgQlS1mqzrxL88/Dk979Dkxsy7@blCw)

Comment: I think `strcmp(s,y[i++])||puts(s=y[i]);` saves you 7 bytes.

Comment: @Neil Clever, was thinking there must be a away to just keep on looping - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>102</s> 79 bytes

```python
a='fizz'
b='buzz'
def f(s):t={'Python':a,a:b,b:"'ave a banana"}[s];print t;f(t)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY2xDsIwDET3fIWVxa2UidFV/oEdMThtIrqkUWMQLeLbQ0jFgm/wSWffS5vclngqhS2Ged9ROYvu/jWTDxC63JPYF57bHRIbJmccaeSHBwbHsUq/L/k6pHWOAjKETvoSlhUyzBF@rwYOQN2t38BfRw3YjROSAlk3amwF/jn6JASJc1ZwILSto8sH)

Uses a different approach from the other answer, recursive function

Edit: Thanks @SurculoseSputum for saving 23 bytes!

Comment: You can get it down to [91 bytes](https://tio.run/##bY4xDsIwDEV3n8LK4lSqGBiDcgeuYNMYsoQKDBJFnD2EIBZUe7He/1/f88NO57KtlSNpXhYCiSS3zzElRfXXIQBafNK@OynwyEFGCY74npBRuLR1r80xWXMDZkUL8yUXQ9upt6Gq/6UH@AoutnEATemtK7w/scJZDtMfr28) by rearranging everything a bit.

Comment: [79 bytes](https://tio.run/##XY2xDsIwDET3fIWVxa2UidFV/oEdMThtIrqkUWMQLeLbQ0jFgm/wSWffS5vclngqhS2Ged9ROYvu/jWTDxC63JPYF57bHRIbJmccaeSHBwbHsUq/L/k6pHWOAjKETvoSlhUyzBF@rwYOQN2t38BfRw3YjROSAlk3amwF/jn6JASJc1ZwILSto8sH) if terminating the function with exception is allowed.

Comment: @SurculoseSputum well, your answer uses exceptions i think, so sure, thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>52</s> 47 bytes

```
∧"Brachylog
fizz
buzz
'ave a banana"ṇ;?⟨a₁h⟩b~ṇ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6kUFCUn1KanFpspfRwV@fDHduApH31o7YNj5qa9R51rFDSSEvMzCktStVUqoUrqH24dcL/Rx3LlZxgZnGlZVZVcSWVAgn1xLJUhUSFpMQ8IFR6uLPd2v7R/BWJj5oaMx7NX5lUBxT5/z9aKS2xOCVNSUcJpBFIwU0CskHGACmv1JycSiCNamAsAA)

The predicate fails on inputs on which it should "terminate". If outputting an unbound variable is more desirable, +2 bytes for `.∨`; if an empty string is necessary, +1 on top of that for `Ẹ`.

Answer (score 2):

### Kotlin, 103 bytes

```
fun f(x:String){listOf("fizz","buzz","'ave a banana").fold("Kotlin"){a,b->if(x==a){println(b);f(b)};b}}
```

[Try it online!](https://pl.kotl.in/k5cal-_iM)